# Why is my post request flagged as unauthorized when using AllowAny permission class

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a request which take POST headers only and I have used the permission_classes([AllowAny]) decorator as below:

```
@api_view(["POST"])
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
def endpoint(request):
   print(request.data)
   return Response({"status": "success"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

and have also tried switching order of decorators:

```
@permission_classes([AllowAny])
@api_view(["POST"])
def endpoint(request):
   print(request.data)
   return Response({"status": "success"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

However whenever I make the request it is blocked as unauthorized. I have also tried to make the request crsf_excempt and that responds with - WSGIRequest object has no attribute 'data'.

I am running on django 2.2.5

Comment: Your default authentication classes might be kicking in, so try adding `@authentication_classes([])` if you really want unauthenticated users to be able to access this.

Answer (score 0):

if you are authorized add IsAuthenticated to permission class to get auth info

Comment: The point is to be able to access the endpoint without authentication, so a user without a login can access the resource